# UIViewController is deallocated before delegate method is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have `PreviewController` : `UIViewController` which is used to show document in full screen it's part of `UINavigationViewController`.
Also it's delegate of `UISplitViewController`.

When it's pushed, it hides `masterView` of `UISplitViewController`. (Methods 1 - 3 - 2 are called)

When it disappears (by pressing "back" button), it shows `masterView` of `UISplitViewController`. (Methods 4 - 2 are called)

But there is a way to force closing `PreviewController`. In this case only method 4 is called and `PreviewController` is deallocated before `UISplitViewController` can send message and call Method 2.

How can I resolve this problem? Is there a way to force `UISplitViewController` to call it's delegate method? Or can I retain `PreviewController` in Method 4 and release it in Method 2 (using ARC)?

```
// Method 1
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.hideMaster = YES;
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] splitViewController];
    splitViewController.delegate = self;
}

// Method 2
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return self.hideMaster;
}

// Method 3
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.hideMaster = YES;
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] splitViewController];
    [splitViewController.view setNeedsLayout];
    [splitViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation duration:0];
}

// Method 4
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.hideMaster = NO;
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] splitViewController];
    [splitViewController.view setNeedsLayout];
    [splitViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation duration:0];
}

// PreviewController is created in UIViewController which belongs to UINavigationController
PreviewController *previewVC = [[PreviewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PreviewController" bundle:nil];
previewVC.documentURL = url;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:previewVC animated:YES]
```

Comment: Where and how is your PreviewController instance created? Can you post code for that as well?

Comment: Added this information in question section.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently not holding any strong reference to your PreviewController instance.
It should be enough to add a strong class property in your interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PreviewController *previewVC;
```

And then create the instance by using:

```
self.previewVC = [[PreviewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PreviewController" bundle:nil];
```

This ensures the PreviewController will not be deallocated while your view controller is alive (unless you release it yourself).

Comment: You helped me partly. PreviewVC is not deallocated but delegate method isn't still called. :(

Comment: I found solution. I added splitViewController.delegate = self; in method #4. Delegate for splitViewController was changed in other UIViewController, that's why it wasn't called :(